# Oracle - Need to capture change in data rows in a table without using triggers

Tags: oracle

Need to capture change for each column for each row in a table without using triggers

Before:
Id Name Address
1  A      LUCKNOW
2  B      PUNE

After:

Id Name Address
1  A     DELHI
2  B     PUNE

Need to capture the change for id =2 and report the column that was changed.
Can this be achieved without using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

If your Oracle is 11.2.0.4+ take a look at Flashback Data Archive.

```
CREATE FLASHBACK ARCHIVE test_archive
   TABLESPACE <your_ts>
   QUOTA 1 M
   RETENTION <some_period> DAY;
 
ALTER TABLE <your_table>
   FLASHBACK ARCHIVE;
```

[For reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5011.htm#SQLRF20008)

Comment: I need to write something that dynamically insert records as an audit into any table at run time changes

Comment: And how will you hook into the process that inserts the information? The idea of the trigger or any other audit is that you will not need to change your client code to do supplementary work for the change logging.